# React Tutorial - Can only update a mounted or mounting component error

Tags: reactjs

I am following the React tutorial at the following [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)
and when I start the app, I run into the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the CommentBox
>   component.

The application seems to be running fine; however the console keeps on showing the error.

Here is the code for my CommentBox component:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
              console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
          });
        },
        handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
          $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: comment,
            success: function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
              console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
          });
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {data: []};
        },
        componentDidMount: function() {
          this.loadCommentsFromServer();
          setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
        },
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="commentBox">
              <h1>Comments</h1>
              <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
              <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
            </div>
          );
        }
      });
```

I have read through the [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) page but I have a hard time understanding what could be wrong.

Comment: Is `componentWillUnmount` being called?

Comment: Can you share the console error ?

Comment: @FurkanO : I shared the console error in the block quote.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli : I literally copy pasted what was in the tutorial. I shared the link if you have a time to go through it.